# java IntStream cannot use collect(Collectors.toList()), compilation error, why?

Tags: java, compilation, java-stream, collect, tolist

As below:

```
    IntStream iStream = IntStream.range(1,4);
    iStream.forEach(System.out::print);
    List list1 = iStream.collect(Collectors.toList());//error!
```

Java 1.8 compiler gives type deduction error. Similar code could work for String type:

```
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    ls.add("abc");
    ls.add("xyz");
    List list2 = ls.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Why? Does IntStream/LongStream/DoubleStream are not working the same way like other types? How to fix my compilation error?

Comment: Call `boxed ()` before collecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IntStream` (along with the other primitive streams) does not have a `collect(Collector)` method. Its collect method is: [`collect(Supplier,ObjIntConsumer,BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

If you want to collect the `int`s into a `List` you can do:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);
```

Or you can call [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Both options will box the primitive `int`s into `Integer`s, so which you want to use is up to you. Personally, I find the second option simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 7):

The primitive streams don't have the same `collect` method as `Stream`. You can convert them to a stream of the wrapper type in order to use the `collect` method that accepts a `Collector` argument:

```
List<Integer> list1 = iStream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```